# Issue with Web Api Custom Model Binder in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using Mvc4 with WebApi.
I am using Dto objects for the webApi.
I am having enum as below.

```
public enum Status
{
 [FlexinumDefault]
  Unknown = -1,
  Active = 0,       
  Inactive = 100,   

}
```

Dto structure is as follows.

```
[DataContract]
public class abc()
{
[DataMemebr]
[Required]
int Id{get;set;}

[DataMember]
[Required]
Status status{get;set}
}
```

I have created Custom Model Binder which will validate the enum(status) property in the dto object and return false if the enum value is not passed.

if the status enum property is not passed in the dto object,we should throw exception

```
 public bool BindModel(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var input = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);


            if (input != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.AttemptedValue))
            {
                if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(Enum))
                {
                    //var actualValue = null;
                    var value = input.RawValue;
```

in the api controller,i have action method like

```
public void Create([FromUri(BinderType = typeof(EnumCustomModelBinder))]abcdto abc)
        {
```

In global.asax.cs
i have set like

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.BindParameter(typeof(Enum), new EnumCustomModelBinder());
```

the issue i am facing is the custombinder

```
var input = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
```

,the input value is coming as null.

Please sugggest

---

Comment: What are you trying to do? You may not even need a custom enum model binder...

Comment: I am trying to validate the Enum (for example: if I am passing the request with out Status property which is of Enum type then I should be able to validate the enum value by default it is making as unKnown which i dont want to pass to controller).I should be able to validate the enum type before binding to model and add to model error if the enum value is Unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

This works fine,but the default implementation of model binder is missing.

```
public bool BindModel(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var json = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                var jsonObject = (JObject) Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                var jsonPropertyNames = jsonObject.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

                var requiredProperties = bindingContext.ModelType.GetProperties().Where(p =>p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute),
                                                                                           false).Any()).ToList();

                var missingProperties = requiredProperties.Where(bindingProperty => !jsonPropertyNames.Contains(bindingProperty.Name)).ToList();

                if (missingProperties.Count > 0)
                {

                    missingProperties.ForEach(
                        prop =>
                            {
                                if (prop.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                                    actionContext.ModelState.AddModelError(prop.Name, prop.Name + " is Required");

                            });
                }

                var nullProperties = requiredProperties.Except(missingProperties).ToList();

                if (nullProperties.Count > 0)
                {
                    nullProperties.ForEach(p =>
                        {
                            var jsonvalue = JObject.Parse(json);
                            var value = (JValue)jsonvalue[p.Name];
                            if (value.Value == null)
                            {
                                actionContext.ModelState.AddModelError(p.Name, p.Name + " is Required");
                            }

                        });
                }

            }
            // Now we can try to eval the object's properties using reflection.
            return true;
        }
```